# ups tracking api - set response language

Tags: php, xml, api, tracking, ups

I have a php solution for ups tracking.
The response which I get from UPS using the language "english"
Is there an way to get another language for the response?

This is my code from the ups developer documentation:
This is my code from the ups developer documentation:
This is my code from the ups developer documentation:
This is my code from the ups developer documentation:This is my code from the ups developer documentation:

```
// Configuration
$accessLicenseNumber = "xxx";
$userId = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$endpointurl = 'https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Track';


try {

    // Create AccessRequest XMl
    $accessRequestXML = new SimpleXMLElement ( "<AccessRequest></AccessRequest>" );
    $accessRequestXML->addChild ( "AccessLicenseNumber", $accessLicenseNumber );
    $accessRequestXML->addChild ( "UserId", $userId );
    $accessRequestXML->addChild ( "Password", $password );

    // Create TrackRequest XMl
    $trackRequestXML = new SimpleXMLElement ( "<TrackRequest></TrackRequest  >" );
    $request = $trackRequestXML->addChild ( 'Request' );
    $request->addChild ( "RequestAction", "Track" );
    $request->addChild ( "RequestOption", "activity" );

    $trackRequestXML->addChild ( "TrackingNumber", "xxx" );

    $requestXML = $accessRequestXML->asXML () . $trackRequestXML->asXML ();

    $form = array (
            'http' => array (
                    'method' => 'POST',
                    'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'content' => $requestXML
            ) 
    );

    // get request
    $request = stream_context_create ( $form );
    $browser = fopen ( $endpointurl, 'rb', false, $request );
    if (! $browser) {
        throw new Exception ( "Connection failed." );
    }

    // get response
    $response = stream_get_contents ( $browser );
    fclose ( $browser );

    if ($response == false) {
        throw new Exception ( "Bad data." );
    } else {    

        // get response status
        $resp = new SimpleXMLElement ( $response );
    }

    Header ( 'Content-type: text/xml' );
} catch ( Exception $ex ) {}
}
```

Comment: The language seems to be defined in the `<AccessRequest xml:lang="en-US">` tag.

Comment: yes, i tried this before `$accessRequestXML = new SimpleXMLElement ( "<AccessRequest xml:lang='de_DE'></AccessRequest>");` and `$accessRequestXML = new SimpleXMLElement ( "<AccessRequest xml:lang='de-DE'></AccessRequest>");` - but it still stay in english

Comment: Did you check the output of your request (`$requestXML`) before to send it ? Is the format is OK ?

Comment: the format should be okay, otherwise i don't get a correct response, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is. I thought mostly about the format of the `xml:lang="de-DE"`.

Comment: @Ghost108 You have changed the language. I have your same problem. How can I do?

Comment: I didnt find a solution. :(

Comment: @Ghost108 I wrote an email to the developers assistance, if they answer me I'll let you know

Comment: That is great. Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this via XML, you need to use WSDL (SOAP) or JSON.
You can use the Local TAG in  `/TrackRequest/Locale` => `<v3:Locale>it_IT</v3:Locale>`

WSDL (SOAP) Request

url for test webservices [https://wwwcie.ups.com/webservices/Track](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUTLq.png)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:v1="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/UPSS/v1.0"
xmlns:v3="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Track/v2.0"
xmlns:v11="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Common/v1.0">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <v1:UPSSecurity>
            <v1:UsernameToken>
                <v1:Username>USERID</v1:Username>
                <v1:Password>PASSWORD</v1:Password>
            </v1:UsernameToken>
            <v1:ServiceAccessToken>
                <v1:AccessLicenseNumber>API KEY</v1:AccessLicenseNumber>
            </v1:ServiceAccessToken>
        </v1:UPSSecurity>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <v3:TrackRequest>
            <v11:Request>
                <v11:RequestOption>1</v11:RequestOption>
                <v11:TransactionReference>
                    <v11:CustomerContext>Your Test Case Summary Description</v11:CustomerContext>
                </v11:TransactionReference>
            </v11:Request>
            <v3:Locale>it_IT</v3:Locale>
            <v3:InquiryNumber>TRACKING NUMBER</v3:InquiryNumber>
        </v3:TrackRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I did some tests using the Tracking Number of tests and with those it does not work.
I then used a **true tracking code** sent to my country (Italy) and it works

RESPONSE WSDL(SOAP)

```
..........
<trk:Status>
   <trk:Type>M</trk:Type>
   <trk:Description>Ordine elaborato: Pronto per UPS</trk:Description>
   <trk:Code>MP</trk:Code>
</trk:Status>
..........
```

I used Postman to make requests

[image]

You can also use JSON (See the guide on the UPS website)

Comment: that means, I can realize it only with php and json / soap? :( => I have no experience with that :(

Comment: @Ghost108 to get the translations in your language yes

Answer (score 0):

This is the example of a soap client from the development kit UPS

```
<?php

  //Configuration
  $access = " Add License Key Here";
  $userid = " Add User Id Here";
  $passwd = " Add Password Here";
  $wsdl = " Add Wsdl File Here ";
  $operation = "ProcessTrack";
  $endpointurl = ' Add URL Here';
  $outputFileName = "XOLTResult.xml";

  function processTrack()
  {
      //create soap request
    $req['RequestOption'] = '15';
    $tref['CustomerContext'] = 'Add description here';
    $req['TransactionReference'] = $tref;
    $request['Request'] = $req;
    $request['InquiryNumber'] = '';
    $request['TrackingOption'] = '02';

    echo "Request.......\n";
    print_r($request);
    echo "\n\n";
    return $request;
  }

  try
  {

    $mode = array
    (
         'soap_version' => 'SOAP_1_1',  // use soap 1.1 client
         'trace' => 1
    );

    // initialize soap client
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl , $mode);

    //set endpoint url
    $client->__setLocation($endpointurl);


    //create soap header
    $usernameToken['Username'] = $userid;
    $usernameToken['Password'] = $passwd;
    $serviceAccessLicense['AccessLicenseNumber'] = $access;
    $upss['UsernameToken'] = $usernameToken;
    $upss['ServiceAccessToken'] = $serviceAccessLicense;

    $header = new SoapHeader('http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/UPSS/v1.0','UPSSecurity',$upss);
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);


    //get response
    $resp = $client->__soapCall($operation ,array(processTrack()));

    //get status
    echo "Response Status: " . $resp->Response->ResponseStatus->Description ."\n";

    //save soap request and response to file
    $fw = fopen($outputFileName , 'w');
    fwrite($fw , "Request: \n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n");
    fwrite($fw , "Response: \n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "\n");
    fclose($fw);

  }
  catch(Exception $ex)
  {
    print_r ($ex);
  }

?>
```